# How to sort Apache Solr search results?

Tags: search

I want to make possible for the user to SORT Apache Solr results based on some taxonomy terms.How can I do that?
I also want to make possible for a user to change the number of the results on the page.
How can I achieve both of them?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to ask multiple questions, especially in this case, where the way you solve the first question will effect how you can solve the second question.

Answer (score 5):

I good way to utilize Solr for search with Drupal, is to use the [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api), is has a [Solr integration module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), which will allow you to setup a View with exposed filters and full text search. With the flexibility of Views, you should be able to setup the view to allow the users to sort as they wish.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this comes too late for you but maybe will help someone else:

(1) Sorting can be handled with Facets:
    Facet API  ( facetapi )

(2) # of results per page sounds like a Drupal configuration thing, maybe handled in the configuration of the Block in which you show the search results

Comment: Hello and welcome. This looks a bit more like speculation than a real answer. Could you please expand it a bit, especially first part, as you seem to know it pretty well?

Comment: Hello, 
re: (1) I tried Facet API module & it provides ways to drill down in search. You can sort by relevancy, date, author, date... customized in the Facet tab in ApacheSolr settings (if Facet is enabled).
  
When these terms are exposed, they become available in Blocks.
  
Taxonomy ("Filter by field of type taxonomy_term_reference.") is one of the items exposed.
I haven't used it, but it's there.
  
Perhaps I misunderstood Sokratis' question? 
  
re:(2) # of results, I was wrong, they are not configured in Blocks. Looks like it's in the 'configure display' link for whatever term is exposed.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Could you please edit it inside your answer? I would like to do it myself, but I'm afraid to mess it up.